# Open Multiple Browser Windows with ADB on Quest 2/Pro in multi-window mode

Tags: adb, oculusquest

MQDH has an open browser option which can also be achieved through ADB. However, the browser always opens in the main central window.

How do I specify which window area to open the browser in using ADB?

I can open a single browser using the following:

`am start -n com.oculus.vrshell/.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -d apk://com.oculus.browser -e uri "www.google.com"`

But this only opens the browser in the central window. Launching it again just creates a new tab. How do I open the browser in a specific window while using the multi-window mode on Quest.

I do not mind if I can achieve the same with something like AutoDriver - But I have not been able to do so.